# sending a custom object from spring-xd to gemfire

Tags: spring-xd

Hello i have problem about writing an object that i defined from sprin-xd to gemfire.

if deploy my class and if i write following command to gemfire console i can create new entry in region which contains object of Employee class.

```js
put --key-class=java.lang.String --value-class=Employee --key=('id':'998') --value=('id':186,'firstName':'James','lastName':'Goslinga') --region=replicated2
```

The think that i want to do is i will send data from spring-xd. And i will have a new object of Employee class in Gemfire.

If i create such stream which will get data from rabbit MQ and send it to gemfire.

```js
stream create --name reference-data-import --definition "rabbit --outputType=text/plain | gemfire-json-server --host=MC0WJ1BC --regionName=region10 --keyExpression=payload.getField('id')" --deploy
```

I can see that data in this type of "com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxInstanceImpl".

Regarding to spring-xd documentation i can use such parametter outputType=application/x-java-object;type=com.bar.Foo but i never managed to work it out even though i deploy my class. if i can see a simple working example it will be great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Spring XD provides no facilities for automatically converting from one object type to another since there is no easy way to handle the mapping in an automated way.  Instead, you'll need to create a transformer before the `gemfire-server` sink to convert to your com.bar.Foo object.  From there, it will be serialized correctly into Gemfire.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Michael. Is there a simple example which makes this transformation? I understood it needs to be serialized but i don't know how to make this transformation. That is why a simple example may help a lot.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/pivotal/IoT-ConnectedCar/tree/master/IoT-GemFireTransformer